# Update any datasource using dataset,datadapter from a XML file

Tags: xml, ado.net, dataset, dataadapter

I am trying to update a access db using DataSet. The DataSet reads an xml and then using update of DataAdapter Update function tries to update the database.

Below is the code

```
    OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(this.ConnectionString);
    connection.Open();
    var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Customer", connection);
    adapter.ContinueUpdateOnError = true;
    var dataSet = new DataSet();
    dataSet.ReadXml("Update.xml");
    OleDbCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);
    foreach (DataRow row in dataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        row.AcceptChanges();
        row.SetModified();
    }
    var result = adapter.Update(dataSet, "Customer");
```

And here is the xml

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Customer>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <CustomerName>Customer 1</CustomerName>
  </Customer>
  <Customer>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <CustomerName>Customer 2</CustomerName>
  </Customer>
</NewDataSet>
```

The IDs (1,2) exists in access database. I am trying to update them..
Update function return 2, which is the number of rows updated but I don't see the updation in access database. ID field is auto incremented

However, if I run the following

```
    foreach (DataRow row in dataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        row["CustomerName"] = "Hi";
    }
    var result = adapter.Update(dataSet, "Customer");
```

Then the update gets refelected correctly in database.Please help

Answer (score 0):

Is this using an access database that is part of the project? Get properties on the access db file - is it set to "CopyAlways" when the project is built? If so, then the access db in the main project directory is being copied to the BIN directory each build. Your app will probably update the DB in BIN

Either you're looking in the DB in your project and finding no changes (it was never that DB file that was updated) or you're looking in the DB in BIN folder but not realising that every time build is done, the file is overwritten with clean copy -> looks like no changes get saved between successive runs of the app

http://www.vbdotnetforums.com/showthread.php/18096-FAQ-quot-My-database-isnt-saving-changes-quot-or-quot-Changes-are-gone-when-I-restart-the-app-quot?p=54914#post54914

If this isn't the case, I think then the problem may be rooted in the versions of the row in the datatable. Use a .NET decompiler to have a look at the code of the dataadapter.Update method and see if it is comparing the Row [indexed by DataRowVersion] Original and Current values in some way..

Or maybe the update query built by the dataadapter (use the debugger locals window to inspect it) has some form of optimistic concurrency - this means it looks like

```
UPDATE people SET name = @newName WHERE ID = @originalID and @name = @originalName
```

If the @originalname parameter is filled with a new value (from your xml file), not the value currently in the database table, then the query updates 0 records. Optimistic concurrency is used to detect changes by 2 people to the same row, and the logic basically means you can only change a row from oldValue to newValue if the row in the DB is still having that oldValue. When we use DB normally, dataset knows what is original value - it's what we download from the DB. When you set new value, DataSet knows that this is new value, but still remembers old value so that it can fill in (different) values for @oldName and @newName parameters, and the query just works unless someone else changed the DB before you managed to

Normally though in that case where the wrong @oldValue is used, the dataadapter will throw a ConcurrencyViolation "the update command influenced 0 of 1 expected rows"

I didn't find any way to turn off optimistic concurrency in DbCommandBuilder docs, you have to overwrite the UPDATE statement yourself with another one that doesnt have this pattern of using @oldValue also

It may be that you end up approaching the problem in slightly different way:

Download all database data into table, read xml into another dataset, loop through other dataset updating values in dataset from database, dataadapter.update the dataset that came from the DB

Or, simpler, read the dataset in from xml, loop over it executing an update command directly to the db for every row